# pipe compressed stream to another process using ffmpeg subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to get compressed data from camera and send it to client side before converting it to frames. I have created a dummy code. but i am getting error that `cannot reshape array of 0 byte`

```py
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import numpy

IMG_W = 640
IMG_H = 480

FFMPEG_BIN = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
ffmpeg_cmd = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-i', 'h264.h264',
            '-vcodec', 'h264',              # disable audio processing
            '-f', 'image2pipe', '-']   

ffmpeg_cmd2 = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-i','image2pipe',
            '-r', '30',                 # FPS
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',        # opencv requires bgr24 pixel format.
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
            '-an','-sn',                # disable audio processing
            '-f', 'image2pipe', '-'] 

 
pipe = sp.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10)
 
pipe2 = sp.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd2, stdin = pipe.stdout,stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10)

while True:
    raw_image = pipe2.stdout.read(IMG_W*IMG_H*3)
    image =  numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')     # convert read bytes to np
    image = image.reshape((IMG_H,IMG_W,3))

    cv2.imshow('Video', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

pipe.stdout.flush()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you check `raw_image` if it is empty

Comment: yes empty i have checked

Comment: That is the reason of the error, handle it with if clause

Comment: Can you please figure out in code. Sir

Comment: Hey no need to call sir. So you have understood that your image is empty that is why this line `image =  numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')` is failing. Now all the code after this like and this line should be inside a `if` statement, i.e. you want to run them only if the image is not empty.

Comment: Still no frames producted Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Output #0, image2pipe, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv422p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder  : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   1...      0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=23 drop=0 speed=   0x